# Can Jmeter record apps installed on panasonic tablets having windows 7 OS?

Tags: jmeter

There are Panasonic made tablets having o/s Windows-7. Two applications are installed on these devices.Can Jmeter record these apps?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter can record any HTTP or HTTPS requests which are going through its [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

If your 2 applications do network communication via aforementioned protocols you should be able to record them using the following steps:

1. Launch JMeter Proxy Server
2. Configure tablets to use WiFi rather then cellular data
3. Make sure that tablets and the host running JMeter are on the same network/subnet
4. Open port 8080 in JMeter's host firewall
5. Configure tablets to use JMeter's host as a proxy
6. Start applications and execute your test scenario

See [Load Testing Mobile Apps. But Made Easy.](http://blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-mobile-apps-made-easy) guide for details.